# javascript source code img

Tags: javascript, image, url, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension to download images of websites.
I'm looking for a way to do that. More especially, website which use javascript to go to the next image, so I need a way to find the url of the image and then go for the next image and find its url ... till the `404` error page.
But the first step is to do that on the first page, so that's why I'm here.

The source code of the website is like :

```
<span class="next" id="lel"><img src="http://lel.site.com:8080/name/9264/32309/3_713641d7cf1a3807bc2a7e38dbbe8189.png?zoneID=95051&amp;pageID=1616841&amp;siteID=3174&amp;st=ySF1vI_OmDkLcs7TUHaxAQ&amp;e=1525741200" border="0" id="image_lel" class="pointer" style="opacity: 1; margin-left: 0px; height: 1150px; width: 800px; position: relative; left: 0px; visibility: visible;"></span>
```

I tryed some javascript executed in a popup extension, like :

```
<script>
var sourdeCode = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var someimage = document.getElementById('the_id_of_the_image');
var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var the_url = myimg.src;
</script>
```

But, as expected it does not work.
Could someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Try `var the_url = someimage.src;` instead

Comment: just tried, but still not working

Comment: someimage line makes no sense at all. Simply do myimg = document.getElementsByTagName('img') and enumerate the result, look for examples of enumerating images or other elements, there are tons of them.

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and don't use inline JavaScript, it doesn't work in extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use document.getElementsByTagName() to get all images in the DOM:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

You can also use the document.images collection.

And, if you can use jQuery, you can also use $('img') which gives you a jQuery object containing all img elements.

```
var srcList = $('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Note: The above code will help you read all the images available in the current DOM. You may have to employ some logic to grab the images if being loaded dynamically(on some events).